# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<{}, {}>'

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I want to put a post on a test server, but I find two errors when using Map and Subscribe.
Note that below I use both in the consultaCEP() and it works.

Using W10, vscode, angular 6.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cadastro',
  templateUrl: './cadastro.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cadastro.component.css']
})
export class CadastroComponent implements OnInit {

  onSubmit(form){
    //console.log(form);

    this.http.post('https://httpbin.org/post', JSON.stringify(form.value));
    .map(res => res)
    .subscribe(dados => console.log(dados));

  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

}
```

```
  consultaCEP(cep, form){
        this.http.get(`//viacep.com.br/ws/${cep}/json`)
          .map(dados => dados)
          .subscribe(dados => this.populaDadosForm(dados, form));
      }

    }
  }
```

I expect solve this issues and post on the test server

Comment: Is the semi-colon `(;)` on the end of the first `this.http.post` a typo?

Comment: Not solving issue but... you are mixing rxjs 5 and 6, you should clean out that and choose either (I recommend rxjs 6 of course). You probably have then rxjs-compat package, if your other packages don't need it, you should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to `pipe` your mapping function in order to get this to work:

```
 this.http.post('https://httpbin.org/post', JSON.stringify(form.value));
.pipe(map(res => res))
.subscribe(dados => console.log(dados));
```

besides the `map` function is totally redundant in your case since it just returns the value it receives

For additional information take a look at this [blogpost](https://blog.angularindepth.com/reading-the-rxjs-6-sources-map-and-pipe-94d51fec71c2)